# Running a code in Excel VBA whenever a cell with RTD-function is updated

Tags: vba, excel, rtd

I use VBA in MS Excel 2007 and I have cells with RTD-function that are updated every minute. My code is running just fine, but despite searching for an answer, I have not figured out how to make the code loop whenever new data are introduced in the RTD cells. Is there any simple answer to this question?

Comment: I don't have an RTD feed to test with but you can look at the [Worksheet_Calculate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838823.aspx) event macro. If the RTD value isn't firing off the calculate event, put a formula somewhere like `=<the rtd cell>` so it does.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel VBA there is an event called *Worksheet_Change*. This event is fired when a cell value is changed. I think this event is what you need.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 'write your code here (Target is the cell)
End Sub
```

Comment: If this is a [RTD function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RTD-function-E0CC001A-56F0-470A-9B19-9455DC0EB593) then the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro is not going to fire.

Comment: I didn't try with an actual RTD feed and you are right RTD is not firing. I googled it and found this (http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/549506-rtd-value-changes-not-triggering-worksheet-change-event.html) to solve it.

Comment: Try using the Worksheet_Calculate event. Oops - I see that Jeeped already suggested this.

Comment: First, I didn't see his post while writing answer. Second, you don't need to be mean. Third, I checked post times mine looks earlier (which i do not care).